# If no composite divisor of a positive integer $n$ divides any other composite divisor of $n$ can $n$ have more than three such divisors?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I wrote a program that finds the sequence of such integers and was surprised to find that is https://oeis.org/A217856 (Numbers with three prime factors, not necessarily distinct, except cubes of primes.)  I imagined that as $n$ grew larger the number of such composite divisors would slowly grow, but this appears not to be the case.  I have checked up to n=500000.

For example, 12 is the first number in the sequence because the divisors of 12 are 2,3,4 and 6.  Now ignore the prime divisors and examine the composites that remain, 4 and 6. 4 does not divide 6, so 12 is in the sequence.

Why can't a number with more prime divisors have more such composite divisors?

Comment: If a number has three prime factors, it has at most eight total divisors at all.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question. Is $n$ any number such that there is no prime factor which appears three times?

Comment: @Elliot G Does the example I added help?  In the case of 12, 2*2*3 are the three primes.

Comment: So are you only considering number of the form $p_1p_2p_3$ or $p_1^2p_2$ for distinct primes $p_1,p_2,p_3$?

Comment: Not sure this makes sense.  What's wrong with $p^3$ for some prime $p$?  the only proper composite divisor of that is $p^2$ which divides no other proper composite factor.  For that matter what's wrong with any of the numbers less than $12$?  What's wrong with, say, $10$?

Comment: If for (not necessarily distinct) primes $p_1,\ldots,p_4$ the product $p_1p_2p_3p_4$ divides $n$ then $p_1p_2$ and $p_1p_2p_3$ are composite divisors of $n$ and $p_1p_2 \mid p_1p_2p_3$.

Comment: @lulu I am not the author of A217856.  My criteria happen to match that sequence.

Comment: You claimed that $12$ was the smallest example of what you were searching for.  I don't see a problem with any of the numbers $1,2, \cdots, 11$.   What condition am I missing?

Comment: @lulu the number must have composite divisors, and at least two so we can try to divide one into the other.

Comment: Ah, you didn't include that condition in your post.

Comment: @WimC I was about to post my answer, but I saw it was identical to your comment, with only the further mention that since it applies to four prime factors, it obviously applies to greater than four prime factors as well. Why don't you post that comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $n$ has at least four prime factors. Then there are primes $p,q,r,s$ (not necessarily distinct) such that $pqrs$ is a divisor of $n$. Then $pq$ is a proper composite divisor of $n$, and so is $pqr$. Moreover, $pq$ divides $pqr$.

That is, if $n$ has at least four prime factors, we can always find two composite proper divisors of $n$ such that one is a multiple of the other. In other words, if we cannot find two such divisors, then $n$ can have at most three prime factors.

On the other hand, if $n$ has fewer than three prime factors, then $n$ has no proper composite divisors. So the condition you've given implies that $n$ has exactly three prime factors.

If $n=pqr$ where $p,q,r$ are prime, and $p \ne q$, then the numbers $pr$ and $qr$ are distinct composite proper divisors and not multiples of each other. But the only other possibility is that $n=p^3$, in which case $n$ has only the single proper composite divisor $p^2$.

So, if $n$ satisfies the following conditions:

- $n$ has at least two distinct composite proper divisors
- No two composite proper divisors of $n$ are multiples of each other.

then $n$ is the product of exactly three prime factors, and is not the cube of a prime. Conversely, any product of three prime factors which is not the cube of a prime has these properties.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then it should easily be possible to construct such a number. But it's quite possible such a number is bigger than 500.000. A relatively small example is given by $n = d_0 \cdot d_1 \cdot d_2 \cdot d_3$ where

\begin{align}
d_0 &= 3 \cdot 5 = 15 \\
d_1 &= 5 \cdot 7 = 35 \\
d_2 &= 7 \cdot 13 = 91 \\
d_3 &= 13 \cdot 17 = 221 \\
\end{align}

In other words, $n = 10.558.275$. You can easily extend the construction to an arbitrary number of divisors.

Comment: Divisors of number 10558275: 1, 3, 5, 7, 13, 15, 17, 21, 25, 35, 39, 49, 51, 65, 75, 85, 91, 105, 119, 147, 169, 175, 195, 221, 245, 255, 273, 325, 357, 425, 455, 507, 525, 595, 637, 663, 735, 833, 845, 975, 1105, 1183, 1225, 1275,..., and 15 divides 75, among others.